# Sublime text 3 change focus to next split view pane

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

How can I easily switch the active pane to the next pane in my SplitView ?

Suppose I am working with a vertical split view of 2 screens, and I need to rapidly change the focus from view n°1 to view n°2 to copy paste various elements

Currently I found no other means than to click the other pane to change the focus. Is it possible to have a keyboard shortcut that would cycle through split views ? (Sometimes I have 3 vertical splits and would like to have something similar to the Alt-Tab shortcut but for the split views only.

Answer (score 5):

#### Is it possible to have a keyboard shortcut that would cycle through split views?

I don't think you can cycle, but you can go direct to a view:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1..4</kbd> - Jump to group where num is 1..4

Source [75 Shortcuts for Sublime Text](https://shortcutworld.com/en/Sublime-Text/mac/all#link_6)

Comment: Thanks, for some reason those shortcuts don't work on my sublime, even though they are written in View > Focus Group ... I probably have something interfering on my desktop.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet below will add keyboard shortcuts to navigate forward (<kbd>⌥ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>) and backward (<kbd>⌥ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>) between panes in multi-pane views. Add this to your User keybindings:

```json
{ "keys": ["alt+tab"], "command": "focus_neighboring_group", "args": {"forward": true}},
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+tab"], "command": "focus_neighboring_group", "args": {"forward": false}}
```

Works for me on ST4. Have not tested with earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

I use `⌘`+`⇧`+`{`/`}` to move between tabs.
But it also works across panes.

So if you only have one tab per pane, or you want to switch between the rightmost tab in pane 1 and the leftmost tab in pane 2, this does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

### Sublime Text 4 (Build 4126) on Linux has the following options

Change focus to next tab: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Page Down</kbd>

Change focus to previous tab: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Page Up</kbd>

Change focus to a specific tab: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> etc.

### Notes

- If you use the keyboard shortcut to change focus past the first or last tab, it closes split view and keeps only the current view visible. For example, if you have 3 tabs visible in split view and you are focused on the first tab and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Page Up</kbd>, split view will close and you will only see the content of the first tab. Likewise if you are focused on the third tab and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Page Down</kbd>, then split view will close and you will only see the content of the third tab.
- The number you press with <kbd>Alt</kbd> represents the tabs currently open in the split, *not* the number out of all the tabs. So if you have 3 tabs open but only the first and third tabs are visible in split view, then you would press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> to change focus to the third tab.

### Here's where it is in the menu

[image]